# Instapage - prepopulating forms

Tags: java, html, parameter-passing

I'm building a website on Instapage and I have a form on the homepage with two fields: Name & Email + checkbox. 
I'm forwarding the details in the URL parameter:

```
?name=Example&email=example@gmail.com&heckbox=yes
```

I would like to grab the name, email, and checkbox value and put it into the form as a text.

```
//ClickDimensions Lab Pre-Fill Forms From URL Parameters
//For more information see http://blog.clickdimensions.com/2014/06/pre-fill-forms-from-links-or-webpages.html
//NOTE: This code is provided as a sample only for the purposes of illustration.

//This function gets the parameters from the URL and sets variables for the fields to be pre-filled
function getParm(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);

  //set variables for each of the fields you wish to pre-file
  //reference them by the ID you found for the field when viewing the source
  NameField = document.getElementById("field-b268d8dd6e388aec6d626ce6f054ccda-0");
  EmailField = document.getElementById("field-b268d8dd6e388aec6d626ce6f054ccda-1");
  CheckboxField = document.getElementById("hidden-field-b268d8dd6e388aec6d626ce6f054ccda-2-0");  

  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}

//This function executes the function above and set the values in the fields
window.onload=function execParm() {
    var fieldName = getParm('Name');
    var fieldEmaiil = getParm('Email');   
    var fieldCheckbox = getParm('Checkbox');
    NameField.value = fieldName;
    EmailField.value = fieldEmaiil;
    CheckboxField.value = fieldCheckbox;
}
```

I've been working with webflow/jotform before and the process was way easier and explained on their forums, with instapage, it's unclear.

Could you someone give me a hint in here?
\thx

Answer (score 0):

May be this article will help you https://help.instapage.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005969527-Passing-UTM-parameters-from-the-URL-to-a-hidden-field

Try to put shortcode in the value field like [email]...